# How many Hebrew words are in Gen 15:6, and what do they mean?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, translation-philosophy

How many Hebrew words are in Gen 15:6, and what do they mean in English?  Does the final translation include English words that are not in the Hebrew text but are implied?  Should they then be in brackets?  According to [Gen 15:6](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/gen/15/6/t_conc_15006),
there are only 4 Hebrew words in this verse.  Am I understanding this correctly?  Are these the only Hebrew words "'aman,Yĕhovah,chashab and tsĕdaqah" in this verse?

Comment: There appear to be [five "words"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H9k74.png) in this verse. The word לּוֹ (_lô’_) is a preposition with a pronoun object, which would be your fifth "word" for this verse.

Comment: So are there no Hebrew words for 'he' or 'him' in this verse?

Comment: I wonder when the earliest commentaries of this verse were written.  That could illuminate our understanding of the meaning and intent of this verse. I notice Flavius Josephus said nothing about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I teach biblical Hebrew so here is how I would answer your question if you were my student.

First, there are exactly 5 Hebrew words. Technically, this is the correct answer to your question. But, what's confusing to many beginning students is that many Hebrew words translate into multiple English words. For example, the third Hebrew word, *vayyachsh'veha*, translates into 4 English words, *and-He-attributed-it* (NOTE: 'it' refers to the feminine noun for righteousness).

If your question, then, is how many English words constitute a literal translation of the verse, one possible correct answer is twelve:

*and-he-believed in-GOD and-He-attributed-it to-him righteous*

However, the second-to-last word, llo, can also be reasonably translated as "according to him", which would increase the English word count to 13.

Have fun. Biblical Hebrew can be fascinating, illuminating, and frustrating all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If it's helpful to you, [Scripture 4 All’s interlinear](http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/Hebrew_Index.htm) using the Westminster Leningrad Codex with vowels offers the following:

[image]

And [Biblos Interlinear](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/15-6.htm):
[image]

[Studylight](https://www.studylight.org/desk/interlinear.cgi?search_form_type=interlinear&q1=gen%2015%3A6&ot=bhs&nt=wh&s=0&t3=str_nas&ns=0) offers several additional features, including various OT manuscripts.

Comment: It seems 2803(e) means a verb for 'counted' but it also includes the pronoun for ;he;.  I think the 'he' in this phrase is implied but not included in the definition of the Hebrew word 'chashab'.  A bit misleading, to my mind.

Comment: @Wolfgang There's nothing misleading here! As in many languages, Hebrew verbs are inflected according to their subject, and a pronominal subject is frequently unstated (unlike English). The form *yaḥšōb* can only be 3rd masc. plural, and the semantics of *qal* *ḥšb* require an animate subject: "he". (There are, in fact, two explicit pronouns in this verse: "... counted **it** to **him**.) Please head to [chat] if you would like to discuss further.

Comment: Susan, I went to the chat room you mentioned to discuss this further, but I do not have 20 reputation points required to chat there.

Comment: I see what you mean.  The 2 pronouns are implied as I had suggested earlier.  So the verse would read: "And believed in the LORD and counted it to him for righteousness."  Apparently 'he' is not the 3rd pronoun but is assumed to be indicating Abram.

Comment: @Wolfgang No they are not implied, they are explicit. But they are suffixes/clitics rather than independent words.

Comment: @Wolfgang Sorry about that. You should be able to talk there now if you have further questions.

Comment: These comments suggest my answer provides information that aids this discussion.  If you disagree with the sources I quote, please don't down-vote me.  :)